# P2P TCP between remote desktop sessions

Tags: c#, tcp, .net-4.0, p2p, remote-desktop

We have a P2P application operating on desktop Windows OS machines in a network. The software broadcasts a UDP packet to identify its presence on the network (its IP address) then accepts TCP connections on a predefined port number.

How can this arrangement be made to work between remote desktop sessions within a single session host server?

My understanding is that, between desktop sessions on the same server, the IP address property of either `UdpClient` or `TcpClient` would simply present as the server IP address.  The address itself is not really an issue, but how can I direct a TCP connection from one instance on one desktop, to another instance on another desktop, if both are listening on the same port at the same (server/localhost) destination IP address.

A similar scenario would be trying to establish a TCP connection from a desktop Windows OS machine to one of several instances of the software running on a remote desktop session on the session server.

Do RDS/TS sessions get assigned an individual IP address?  This problem can't be unique to our software.

Comment: First of all, they can not be listening on the same port at the same time. If that were true, something weird would need to happen. So, in general you will only have a single (IP,port) pair per running instance of your program (the fact that they are running in an RD session does not have an impact on the networking side of things).

Comment: @cdavid well the impact that running in an RD session imposes is that two instances on different sessions on the same server cannot listen on the same port, right? But this is the same limitation of running two instances on the same session.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The fact that they run in two different sessions does not change the network configuration. Same would happen if they ran in the same session. So, if you solve that problem, then you will solve the problem of them running in two different sessions as well.